Webpack module federation directory share
I'm starting a new project and I want to reuse my components from an existing project.
Following tutorials, I was able to share js and react files, as well as images and other media. However, instead of declaring each on my components at webpack.config.js, I was wondering if it is possible to share my entire component folder.
I couldn't find an answer either saying that it is impossible nor how to make that.
So, in the case I can share folder, how can I do that. Otherway, what are my options?
webpack.config.js expose:
exposes: {
        "./LeftNav": "./src/index.js",
        "./Button":  "./src/components/button/Button.jsx",
        "./MyComponentsLibrary":  "./src/components/"
      },

Error
ERROR in container entry ./MyComponentsLibrary[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/components/' in '[project_path]'
Complete webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const webpack = require('webpack')

const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })
const dependencies = require("./package.json").dependencies;
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const path = require("path");
const publicUrl = '';
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module.exports = {
  name: "left-nav",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    liveReload: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    headers: {
      'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'unsafe-none'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        }        
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|wav|ogg|mp3)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [   
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed),
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production'),
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
    }),
    
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),

    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "leftNavigation",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        "./LeftNav": "./src/index.js",
        "./Button":  "./src/components/button/Button.jsx",
        "./MyComponentsLibrary":  "./src/components/"
      },
      shared: {
        "react": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies.react
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies["react-dom"],
          eager: true 
        },
        "@mui/material": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies["@mui/material"],
          eager: true 
        },
        "@mui/icons-material": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: dependencies["@mui/icons-material"],
          eager: true 
        },
      }
    })
  ],
};

I tried to change the components path in order to correct any misspellings error, but didn't work.

The following will expose all components in the components directory:
exposes: {
'./components': path.join(PATHS.src, 'components'),

},
Here’s a very nice example where I have 3 projects interacting with each other using module federation:
inner app
container app
second inner app
